# How to specify a log handler class with a required argument using dictConfig syntax?

Tags: python, django, logging

I Would like to use the [Notifiers](https://notifiers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Logger.html) logging handler in Django. I have my loggers specifed using dictConfig syntax.

Here is an example from Notifer's own docs:

```
>>> import logging
>>> from notifiers.logging import NotificationHandler

>>> log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
>>> defaults = {
...    'token': 'foo,
...    'user': 'bar
... }

>>> hdlr = NotificationHandler('pushover', defaults=defaults)
>>> hdlr.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

>>> log.addHandler(hdlr)
>>> log.error('And just like that, you get notified about all your errors!')
```

The dictConfig syntax is like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

How do I add the Notifier handler using the latter syntax? I can't find a way to set the first, required argument to `NotificationHandler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps specify your own factory class to instantiate the handler. That can be done with the `()` syntax described here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-dict-userdef

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @jspcal I found the answer. Define a handler factory like this:

```
def slack_handler_factory():
    return NotificationHandler(
        'slack',
        defaults={
            'webhook_url': SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL,
        },
    )
```

..and one can add it to handlers using the `()`-syntax:

```
...

'handlers': {
    'slack': {
        '()': slack_handler_factory,
        'level': 'WARNING',
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work by adding a new [handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#id4):

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
        },
        'notify': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'notifiers.logging.NotificationHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {  # or you can add any new logger if you want
            'handlers': ['notify'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

#### Update

A solution could be like this by overriding NotificationHandler:

```
class CustomNotificationHandler(NotificationHandler):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         defaults = {
           'token': 'foo,
           'user': 'bar
         }
         super(CustomNotificationHandler, self).__init__('pushover', defaults)
```

and use that in handler in django logging.

```
'notify': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'CustomNotificationHandler',
    },
```

Comment: But in this way you can't specify the arguments to `notifiers.logging.NotificationHandler`.. That was my problem in the first place.

Comment: Yes. Btw, your answer looks great, but can you please have a look into my updated answer. thanks

Comment: Yes, that should work but the factory is more elegant, no ☺️ ?

Comment: Yes, thats much more cleaner :)